# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows even though it was found

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am trying to run a program I wrote in Python and used PYQT6 for the GUI. It worked fine on my PC(Win 11) until I moved it server side(Windows Server 2012). It has gotten to a point now where Python would crash and I'd get the message I have in the title.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled Python, PYQT6, updated the server and still wont work.